# Query From Table Product and Product_Photo Have More Than 1 Image Just Show 1 Image

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table, product and product_photo

```
product:
id     Title
1       Nike
2       Adidas
3       Piero
```

product_photo:

```
id    id_product   photo_path
1          1       /opt/A.png
2          1       /opt/B.png
3          2       /opt/C.png
4          3       /opt/D.png
```

This the query

```
SELECT p.title, p.id FROM product p JOIN (
    SELECT id_product, photo FROM product_photo GROUP BY id_product,photo
    )pr on id_product = p.id;
```

with the query i got result:

```
Title     id_product    path
Nike        1            /opt/A.png
Nike        1            /opt/B.png
Adidas      2            /opt/C.png
Piero       3            /opt/D.png
```

i want the final result like this just 1 image, like grouping

```
Title     id_product        path
Nike        1            /opt/A.png
Adidas      2            /opt/C.png
Piero       3            /opt/D.png
```

any clue, it's hard to remove the same data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregate function

```
SELECT p.title, p.id,max(path)
FROM product p join product_photo pp on   p.id=pp.id_product
group by p.title, p.id
```

Comment: Greats, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `subquery` if the path is different other than `/opt/A.png . . /B. . . /C` :

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, pp.path
FROM product p INNER JOIN
     product_photo pp
     ON p.id = pp.id_product
WHERE pp.id = (SELECT MAX(p1.id) FROM product_photo p1 WHERE p1.id_product = p.id);
```